# backbone.js model.set not persisiting the values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
extendModel: function (Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
             saveSettings: function (value1,value2,value3,value4) {
                this.set({
                    "field1": siteId,
                    "field2": value2,
                    "field3": value3,
                    "field4": value4
                });
               this.save();
            }
        });
        return Model;
    }
```

1. i am getting the values in my function, but not able to persist the
   values back in model. What is the mistake i am doing here.
2. Do i need to call this.save(), if i am not making any API calls.

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/7ZxAJ/
You don't need to call save().

Comment: @TrevorDixon: sorry guys, its working fine... thanks for your fiddle.... the problem was i was not doing a fetch in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the proper ajax calls back to your server? If not, have you checked the url properties of your models? Also, verify with your browser javascript console that the proper ajax type calls are getting executed.